# To use a function prototype or not

Tags: c

When should a function prototype/declaration be used, or is it good practice to always include them? For example:

```
int square_num(int num);

int main(void) {
    return square_num(3);
}

int square_num(int num) {
    return num * num;
}
```

vs.

```
int square_num(int num) {
    return num * num;
}

int main(void) {
    return square_num(3);
}
```

What would be considered best practice, or is it a case-by-case basis?

Comment: That is dependent on the context. For a siple program such as this. I would put the `square_num()` first and avoid the prototype. In a large application I may want to document all the functions first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule is simple: a function should either be defined or declared with a proper prototype before it is used in code.

Both program styles in the question are correct and which one to use is a matter of personal taste or local conventions. I personally prefer the second and would define `square` as `static`.

If the function `square` is used in another module, it should be declared in a header file included in both modules.

Mutually recursive functions require that at least one of them be declared before use.

Older versions of the C Standard allowed the compiler to infer the prototype of function not yet defined at the point of use as taking an unspecified number of arguments and having an `int` return type. This error-prone behavior is no longer condoned by recent versions of the C Standard.

Comment: sure, and in which case should the first form be used vs. the second. Or does it not matter?

Comment: It does not matter, it is purely a matter of preference. The only meaningful thing here is whether it is `static`, which it should be in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case it's required.  Because the function is used after it is defined, it **must** be declared before.

Had you defined `square_num` before it was called you would not need a prototype.

On a side note, old pre-standard C had the concept of an *implicit function declaration* if it was used before it was defined.  Such a function `foo` would be implicitly defined as `int foo()`, i.e. a function taking an unknown number of arguments and returning `int`.  Some compilers still allow this, but you shouldn't depend on this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Nit: "prototype" refers to a particular *style* of a function declaration, not the declaration itself.  A function declaration or definition that specifies the type of the parameter in the parameter list is a prototype:

```
int square_num(int num); // declaration using prototype syntax
int square_num();        // declaration using non-prototype syntax

int square_num(int num)  // definition using prototype syntax
{
  return num * num;
}

int square_num(num)      // definition using non-prototype syntax
  int num;
{
  return num * num;
}
```

You should *always* use prototype syntax unless you are having to support an *ancient* K&R implementation.

What you’re asking about is whether it’s good practice to have a separate declaration for a function defined in the same source file.

This is largely a matter of taste, but I *strongly* recommend going with the second style and defining the function before it is used.  It reduces your maintenance burden if you ever need to change the return type or parameters of the function, as you only need to make that change in one place.  It may not sound like much, but over a large project it can save some heartburn.

It does mean your code reads "backwards", but the tradeoff is worth it IMO.

Comment: "support an ancient K&R implementation"  And in that case, adding prototypes such as `int square_num(int num)` can actually **break** code.  Arguments passed to a function with a full prototype like `int square_num(int num)` will **not** undergo default argument promotions.  But a function defined in K&R style like `int square_num(num) int num; { ... }` expects all arguments to be passed after such promotions.